# Как ускорить алгоритм поиска?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, бинарный-поиск

Есть задача, приложу условие скриншотом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал 2 варианта решения, вроде как оба работаю верно, но на больших числах программа очень долго выполняется и тест по времени не проходится.

Первый вариант:

```py
def find_a_x(X):
    for i in range(X, 0, -1):
        if bin(i).count('1') == 3:
            return i
    return -1
 
 
T = int(input())
 
 
for _ in range(T):
    X = int(input())
    result = find_a_x(X)
    print(result)
```

Вариант с кэшем (не уверен, что кэш правильно реализовал):

```py
def find_a_x(X, cache):
    if X in cache:
        return cache[X]
 
    for i in range(X, 0, -1):
        binary_str = bin(i)[2:]
        if binary_str.count('1') == 3:
            cache[X] = i
            return i
 
    cache[X] = -1
    return -1


T = int(input())


for _ in range(T):
    X = int(input())
    result = find_a_x(X, {})
    print(result)
```

Условие текстом:

> во время лекции кто-то из учеников перехватил управление доской и начал писать какие-то непонятные числа, оказалось что числа были далеко не случайные, Алиса заметила, что написанные на доске 2N чисел разбивались на пары так, что для каждого числа Х находилось число а(Х) такое, что а(Х) равно наибольшему натуральному числу, которое не превосходит Х и содержит при этом ровно три единицы в своей двоичной записи. Если такого числа нет, то а(Х) = -1.

Формат входных данных.
В первой строке единственное число T - количество тестовых кейсов, в i-й следующих T строк содержится i-й тест, заданный единственным натуральным числом.

Пример входных данных:

```
4
1
8
1023
7
```

Ответ:

```
-1
7
896
7
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам следующим образом, по подсказке с оставлением только трёх ведущих единиц:

```py
def a(x):
    if x < 7:
        return -1
    bin_num = bin(x)[2:]
    if bin_num.count('1') > 3:
        return int(remove_el(bin_num), 2)
    elif bin_num.count('1') == 3:
        return x
    else:
        while x > 7:
            x -= 1
            bin_num = bin(x)[2:]
            if bin_num.count('1') > 3:
                return int(remove_el(bin_num), 2)
            elif bin_num.count('1') == 3:
                return x
        return 7


def remove_el(byte_string: str):
    one_c = 0
    iter_c = 0
    for s in byte_string:
        if one_c == 3:
            return byte_string[0:iter_c] + '0' * (len(byte_string) - iter_c)
        if s == '1':
            one_c += 1
        iter_c += 1


n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    print(a(int(input())))
```

И гораздо более элегантное решение, которое мне подсказали с битовым сдвигом:

```py
def a(x):
    r = 7 << 100
    while 6 < r > x:
        r >>= 1
    return r if r > 3 else -1


n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    print(a(int(input())))
```

Comment: крутое второе решение, я не знал

Answer (score 1):

```
def cb(x):
    if x<7:
        return -1
    s=format(x,'b')
    if s.count('1')==3:
        return x
    if s.count('1')>3:
        b=1+s.find('1',1+s.find('1',1+s.find('1')))
        a=s[:b]
        for i in range(b,len(s)):
            a+='0'
        return int(a,2)
    if s.count('1')<3:
        return cb(x-1)


n=int(input())
res=[]
for _ in range(n):
    z = int(input())
    res.append(cb(z))
for y in res:
    print(y)
```

---

```
4
1
8
1023
7

-1
7
896
7
```

---

```
3
1000000000000
2000000000000
3000000000000
962072674304
1924145348608
2886218022912
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, но этот код не пройдет по времени, полагаю, на 100000 очень долго выполняется, скоро прикреплю своё решение, вроде сделал

Comment: Какое место долгое?

Comment: сейчас работает!

Answer (score 0):

если число в своей двоичной записи содержит не меньше трёх единиц, то оставляем только три старшие единицы:

1010111010

1010100000

если число в своей двоичной записи содержит меньше трех единиц, то уменьшаем его на 1:

1000000000

0111111111

если в результате уменьшения получится число, меньше 7 (т.е. 110, 101, 100, 11, 10, 1 или 0), то выводим -1
иначе пропускаем полученное число через алгоритм еще раз.

Comment: Долго ли придётся повторять уменьшение?

Comment: нет, это сто процентов заходит по времни, у меня прошло

Comment: что значит долго, у всех чисел по разному, но времени хватает

Comment: а ты решил Cb' 6 или bb4 или bb5

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, или вы не сдаёте?

Comment: Нет, не сдаю, к сожалению.

Comment: почему, выросли?

Comment: Да, перерос слегка.

Comment: @user504877 вы можете код предоставить?

Comment: неее, его же все просто спишут

Comment: я дал решение, так реализуйте его

Comment: @user504877 реализовал, но уже не прохожу по неправильному ответу

Comment: какой тест не проходит?